# How to address rabbis of a Bet Din in an email

Tags: beit-din-court, kavod

What is the proper salutation and/or way to address the rabbis of a bet din in an email?

Comment: שמעו נא רבותי דיינים מומחים would be cheeky

Comment: Dear Dayanim, or just "Dear Rabbis",

Comment: @Shalom or just "Hello". Not sure there is a canonical answer to this. Context is king. (FWIW my first comment is not a joke.)

Comment: Definitely not שמעו נא המורים

Comment: For all my emails I cc Hashem@gmail.co.il to remind people that hashem is reading all the emails.

Comment: How about למרנן ורבנן חבורתא קדישתא?